# php - Not showing the output from ob_start();

Tags: php, apache, fpm, ob-start

I am trying to run a PHP script in the background after getting the 200 respond from apache, however, it is not working, am facing a little problem with the following code and I am not sure why.

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

ob_start();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// output the array to screen
echo json_encode(['data' => 'foo']);
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: ' . ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
// run the rest of the code in background
```

I am getting the status code 200, but after the full script process is done, the script it outputing the json array above. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue.

I had gzip enabled on the server, so I added the header:

```
header("Content-Encoding: none");
```

after ob_start(); And it works perfectly fine.